# How do I use Format-Table without truncation of values?

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-2.0

I currently have a script that pings servers and checks the status of services running on each server.

I save the output with Out-File but PowerShell places ellipses or "..." after long strings.  I don't want it to do this.  For example:

```
MachineName  ServiceName             Status StartType
-----------  -----------             ------ ---------
SrvGtw01     Test.MyService....       Running
```

I want it to display the full name like:

```
MachineName  ServiceName              Status StartType
-----------  -----------              ------ ---------
SrvGtw01     Test.MyServiceName.Here  Stopped  Disabled
```

I've been reading that you can set the `$FormatEnumerationLimit` preference variable to `-1` and I have tried that but it's not working.  I'm not sure how I should place it in my script.

Comment: I suggest using `Export-CSV` instead of using any of the Format-* commands to output to a file in your situation. The CSV is also far easier to re-use if you need to perform further actions.

Comment: Yes, I think I will just do this.

Comment: @BoogaRoo: To state it explicitly: it really depends on the use case: is it about _further programmatic processing_ (`Export-Csv`, as you suggest, which, incidentally, will make you _lose type information_, so `Export-CliXml` would be a better choice) or is it about _being easy on human eyeballs_ (`Format-Table` / `Out-File`)?

Comment: @mklement0 I agree, the purpose of the output does matter. Though, `Export-CSV` does not necessarily lose type information for a group of objects of a single type. I like the CSV for being the medium point between easy to read and easy to use in scripting. `Export-CliXml` is definitely better for more complex scripting, but harder to just open in a spreadsheet program and sort.

Comment: I have tested with -Wrap argument and it printed what I needed. It has not been exactly what OP described, but may be useful. Example: `gci env: | Format-Table -Wrap`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The **`$FormatEnumerationLimit` preference variable doesn't apply here**, because its purpose is to determine how many elements of a *collection-valued* property to display (e.g, `$FormatEnumerationLimit = 2; [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 1, 2, 3 }` prints (at most) 2 elements from `.prop`'s value and hints at the existence of more with `...`; e.g., `{1, 2...}`).

Instead, you must:

- (a) **ensure that *individual columns* don't truncate their values** on display:

  - Pipe to **`Format-Table -Autosize`** first.
- *and* (b) **ensure that the *overall output width* can fit all columns**:

  - Pipe to **`Out-File -Width` with a sufficiently large value** (don't use `[int]::MaxValue`, though, because every line of tabular output gets padded to that very width<sup>[1]</sup>)
    .

    - **Caveat:** **If you don't set `-Width`** explicitly - as would happen if you just used `>`, for instance - **the *current console window*'s width is used** - whatever it happens to be.

For instance:

```bash
# Assumes that the objects in $results only contain the properties
# of interest (MachineName, ServiceName, Status, StartType); you 
# can also pass an explicit list of output properties to Format-Table, however.
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -Width 512 C:\log.txt -Append
```

Note: To preview the output in the console - which may involve line-wrapping - use
`Out-String -Width 512` instead.

---

<sup>[1] In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) this undesirable last-column padding has been removed.</sup>